# New to Heroku: Error when I push my app to Heroku

Tags: heroku

I have created Heroku account, installed GIT and Heroku successfully. When I run the command

```
git init
heroku git:remote studentmanagementsystem22
git add .
git commit -m "Initial Commit"
```

All the four steps work perfectly fine, but when I run this command

```
git push heroku master
```

it gives me this error,

```
remote: !       Push rejected to naina-sms.
To https://git.heroku.com/naina-sms.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/naina-sms.git'
```

My requirements.txt file looks like this-

```
dj-database-url>=0.5.0
Django>=3.0.6
gunicorn>=20.0.4
psycopg2>=2.8.5
whitenoise>=5.1.0
requests>=2.23.0
```

I think it has something to do with `git add .` command because when I ran that command it just took me to the next line. Please solve my issue.

Comment: You've only shown us the last few lines from your deploy log, and they don't tell us anything useful. We need to see the detailed output above that. Please [edit] all contiguous error and warning lines into your question.

Comment: "I think it has something to do with `git add .` command because when I ran that command it just took me to the next line"—that command doesn't usually show any output.

Comment: Thanks for help, it was the python version issue. I solved it.